# Unable to communicate with ESP8266 via Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I recently bought an ESP8266 (ESP-01, 1M) yet I have been unsuccessful in making it respond at all.

I have attempted to communicate with it using an Arduino Uno running the built-in `BareMinimum` script (and also the script described [here](http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-to-esp8266-serial-commincation/)) to work like an FTDI.

However, when any AT commands are sent to it via the Serial Monitor there is no response whatsoever using either approach.

The red power LED is on, yet the blue LED is always off.

My wiring:

```
GND - GND
RX - RX
TX - TX
VCC - 3v3
CH_PD - 3v3
```

I would love some clues as to how to solve this error,

Comment: You need to swap RX and TX.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, seems like the same problem I spent hours.

Your Arduino TX has a high level of 5V. If you send a message to your ESP with this voltage you will (surely) destroy it. And I think thats happend to you.
So you have to buy a new ESP.

**For the next try:**
If you use a baudrate of 9600 you can just use two 10kOhm resistors to half your TX voltage. (I did this already and it worked without problems)
For sending a message to your Arduino 3.3V from your ESP are enought.
For higher baudrates you can use a logic level converter: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-logic-level-converter

Comment: I didn't know that at all - will attempt a new esp8266. Thanks!